# VB Script RefreshAll in folder (with exception)

Tags: excel, vbscript

*edited to be more specific:*

`VBScript` below runs through entire folder, **opens each *.XLSM file there**, refreshes all data connections and saves updated files one by one. Files are also password protected, but it's not that important.

How to enhance the code to AVOID files in folder, based on part or entire  **filename**? For an example avoid filenames ending with `z` however with still `.xlsm` extension.

*Expected outcome for files located in the same folder:*

> abc123.xlsm (refresh); abc123z.xlsm (avoid); file.xlsm (refresh);
>   testz.xlsm (avoid)

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = False

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\test\").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsm" Then

    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path ,,,,,"x")

    wb.RefreshAll
    wb.Save
    wb.Close

  End If

Next

xl.Quit
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a file you'd avoid?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways. I would maintain a naming convention for the files that is easy to pattern match on. This question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry, one example would be to NOT refresh any file with filename ending with z. Like refresh all xlsm files, except *z.xlsm

Answer (score 0):

you can try use split command.

```
file_path =abc123.xlsm
file_name =split(file_path,".")
```

file_name is an array containing 2 values

file_name (0)=abc123

file_name (1)=xlsm

now you can check if the last char in file_name(0)="Z"

```
if NOT(right(file_name(0),1)="Z") THEN
    do...
ELSE
    do...
END IF
```